# How to access Shared Preferences with C code in Android?

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface, sharedpreferences

Is there a way to read (no need to write) shared preferences with C code in a .so file? I have an app which provides a .so lib to other apps. The Java code of my app only check for the license and write something to shared preferences. The .so lib needs to read the shared preferences everytime it's called by other apps. Is that possible?

If it's not possible with shared preferences is it possible with any other kind of file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ask for the context object in the method of your choice, then access the SharedPreferences like you would with any other api from JNI:

```
jclass clsContext = (*env)->FindClass(env, "android/content/Context");
jclass clsShared = (*env)->FindClass(env, "android/content/SharedPreferences");
jmethodID methodGetSharedPreferences = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, clsContext, "getSharedPreferences", "whatever signature this method has");
```

You're gonna need to study JNI a bit, it's verbose and complex.